# Can I forward (not relay) an email message via Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding

I have a Postfix email server, and I have a bunch of relays set up so that email sent to `user@mydomain.com` goes to `user@preferredemail.com`. With relaying set up, the `FROM` address doesn't change, so the user doesn't just get a bunch of emails `FROM` my domain. This is just fine.

However, I want to set up an account that *does* change the `FROM` address. Thus, if anyone sends an email to `this_user@mydomain.com`, Postfix would *forward* the email to `alternate@gmail.com`. If you were to check the inbox of `alternate@gmail.com`, you would see all the emails come `FROM` `this_user@mydomain.com`, rather than `FROM` the person who originally sent the email address.

In other words, I want Postfix to replicate what all email clients normally do when someone forwards an email to someone else.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that quite easily with .forward files.. no real need to change postfix at all.

Set up the forward file to send it through a script, rewrite the From and To lines.

Comment: However, if you do this, make sure to not create a loop in case the forwarded mail bounces.

Comment: How do I send it through a script? All I can find on .forward files is to put in an email address. That by itself works, but has the same end result as relaying (the sender/from is unchanged). Could you point me to some documentation on .forward files?

Comment: This is a good explanation for RHEL/CentOS : http://www.ispexperts.com.np/?p=664

Comment: Postfix's is similar to local usage: http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html